# корректное использование функции users.getFollowers? в python

Tags: python, парсер, vkontakte-api, web-scraping

дорогие коллеги!
Я хочу,используя функцию `requests.get` получить информацию о друзьях(подписчиках) человека по его id. Когда я пытаюсь выжать информацию о его странице,вроде бы информация,получаемая мною,положительна:

```
version = 5.124
domain = 1
##offset = 0

friend_get_2 = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'
                            + "user_ids=" + str(domain)+'&fields=bdate,city'
                            + "&access_token=" + token
                          +'&v='+str(version))

print(friend_get_2.json())
```

когда же я пытаюсь таким же методом получить информацию о его подписчиках

```
friend_get_3 = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.getFollowers?'
                            + "user_ids=" + str(domain)
                            + '&count=100&offset=1'
                            + "&access_token=" + token
                          +'&v='+"5.124")

print(friend_get_3.json())
```

, то получаю сообщение,что я что что то не учел:

```
{'error': {'error_code': 100, 'error_msg': 'One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id is undefined', 'request_params': [{'key': 'user_ids', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'count', 'value': '100'}, {'key': 'offset', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.124'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'users.getFollowers'}, {'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}]}}
```

Скажите,то нужно добавить,чтобы функция работала корректно?

Comment: так в сообщении явно написано, что не хватает параметра `user_id`, а вы указали `user_ids`, может в этом?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку. Ну серьезно.

```
import vk_api

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='#TOKEN#')
data = vk.method('friends.get', {'user_id': 12345})
print(data)
```

[Документация](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: это то понятно. Но надо было использовать именно requests.get